# App on phone looks very different to android studio rendering

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, rendering

I'm trying to get a fragment to appear, as rendered in android studio on my phone. I have a Samsung S7 which has 1440 x 2560 pixels, so I've selected the Nexus 6 rendering option in Android Studio.

I have setup my fragment so that it is contained in a content file called `content_add_edit_recipe.xml`. My activity, `activity_add_edit_recipe.xml` includes this file, shown below.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/fragment"
         android:orientation="vertical"
      android:name="com.jcg.grocerylistconverter.AddEditRecipeActivityFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_edit_recipe"/>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.jcg.grocerylistconverter.AddEditRecipeActivity">
```

here is activity file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_add_edit_recipe"/>
```

here is the fragment xml for the layout tag (I don't think the rest is relevant right now):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_add_edit_recipe"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.jcg.grocerylistconverter.AddEditRecipeActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_add_edit_recipe">....
```

And here is how the fragment looks in the preview:

[image]

while here is how it appears on the phone:

[image]

I suspect that this is to do with my actual java code in starting the fragment, but I can't figure out for the life of me where/how this is occurring, after tracing through my code the xmls that are inflated.

If nothing is evident from the xmls I will post the code initiating the activity/fragment, but first can someone please point out if something appears off with my xml?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't consider text size and length of text inside while designing layout. You should test your layout with different text length and size inside spinner